# Can't multiply with python

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I have this code:
(`time` = 1s)

```py
timeafterchange = time[:-1]
print(timeafterchange*60)
```

And I get: `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (60 characters)
and not `60`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you don't have `1`, but rather `'1'`, which is a string.

Consider a simple demonstration:

```
>>> 1 * 5
5
>>> '1' * 5
'11111'
```

You might try: `timeafterchange = int(time[:-1])`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `time` is a string. Strings are copied when you use the multiplication operator on them (`*`), that is why you see the result you described. To fix the issue, call the integer constructor, `int()`, around the value of `timeafterchange` so that multiplication behaves like a number. i.e.

```
timeafterchange = int(time[:-1])
```